# Oracle TO_CHAR (timestamp) and timestamp differ in minutes and seconds

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR((current_timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS AM')  AS curr_time, current_timestamp, dbtimezone
FROM dual;
```

The result is:

```
curr_time  2014-05-22 12:05:23 PM
current_timestamp 22-MAY-14 12.39.23.447181000 PM ASIA/CALCUTTA
dbtimezone +00:00
```

why do curr_time and current_timestamp differ by minutes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

because `MM` are month, not minutes... (and 05 is... may)

You have to use `MI`

Change your format to

```
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'
```